# toLocaleString() returns incorrect time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I made a small function, that converts a UNIX timestamp into a `Date` object.
The returned string however, is always 2 hours too early.

```
toDateTime(secs) {
    var t = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
    t.setSeconds(secs);
    return t.toLocaleString('de-DE');
}
```

Function call: `toDateTime(1567873623)`

Expected output: `7.9.2019, 18:27:03 GMT+02:00`

Actual output: `7.9.2019, 16:27:03 GMT+02:00`

Even when manually setting the timezone, the output is false:

`return t.toLocaleString('de-DE', { timeZone: 'UTC' });`

Output: `Output: 7.9.2019, 14:27:03 GMT+00:00`

Is this a bug?
What am I missing?

Comment: is your server using UTC+0?

Comment: To make a Date from a UNIX timestamp, use `new Date(secs * 1000)`.

Comment: `new Date(1567873623000).toLocaleString("de-DE", { timeZone: "CET" })` gives your desired output.

Comment: the problem is because use of `setSeconds` instead of `setUTCSeconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct a Date instance with year, month, and day values, you get a date that is in your local time zone (which appears to be 2 hours ahead of GMT).  Instead, construct a Date with the constructor that accepts a timestamp value directly; that's always interpreted as a UTC-based reference:

```
  var t = new Date(secs * 1000);
```

By default, `.toLocaleString()` will use your local time zone, so that'll come out as 18:00 as you desired.

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks a lot. My mistake was indeed in constructing the date instance in the wrong timezone!